# Using a Puppet Definition in Site.pp

Tags: puppet

I am using the following Puppet definition to disable IPV6 in windows:

```
#IPv6 Management
define winconfig::ipv6 (
  $ensure,
  $state = UNDEF,
) {
  include winconfig::params
  case $ensure {
    'present','enabled': {
      case $state {
        UNDEF,'all': { $ipv6_data = '0' }
        'preferred': { $ipv6_data = '0x20' }
        'nontunnel': { $ipv6_data = '0x10' }
        'tunnel': { $ipv6_data = '0x01' }
        default: { $ipv6_data = '0' }
      }
    }
    'absent','disabled': { $ipv6_data = '0xffffffff' }
    default: { fail('You must specify ensure status...') }
  }
  registry::value{'ipv6':
    key    => 'hklm\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters',
    value  => 'DisabledComponents',
    type   => 'dword',
    data   => $ipv6_data,
  }
  reboot {'ipv6':
    subscribe => Registry::Value['ipv6'],
  }
}
```

In Site.pp on the master I am using the follwing to call it from a node:

```
node 'BMSGITSS1' { 
# Disable IPV6
  winconfig::ipv6 {
    ensure => 'disabled',
  }
}
```

I get the following error when running puppet agent -t

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could
 not parse for environment production: All resource specifications require names
; expected '%s' at /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/manifests/site.pp:55 on node bmsgitss1 
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint is in the error:

```
All resource specifications require names; expected '%s'
```

You need to give it a name:

```
winconfig::ipv6{"Disable IPv6":
  ensure => 'disabled',
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that has resolved the issue I do get the next Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Puppe
t::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type
winconfig::ipv6 at /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/manifests/site.pp:56 on node bmsgitss1

Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping rune however following on I get:

Comment: `ArgumentError: Invalid resource type` normally means your modulepath or class structure is to blame, as it can't find the `winconfig::ipv6` definition. I'd probably submit a new question with that issue, possibly in server fault as it's on the server itself.